# How do I set and delete some cookies in one page

Tags: php, cookies

I understand that a call to **setcookie()** must be sent before any output from the script, because it is part of the HTTP headers.

In my script I need a loop of 10 sites, for each site -

1. setcookie("TestCookieNameN", $valueN);             // Set a login cookie.
2. Read a file from site N
3. Output the file content
4. setcookie ("TestCookieNameN", "", time() - 3600); // Reset the login cookie
5. continue the loop with site N+1

so how can I delete the cookie in the first site, after I output the file content?
and then move on to other sites ?

Comment: I think it is better to set different cookies for different site .

Comment: ok, I will use value[N], but how do I call the setcookie in the 4th step, after some output?

Comment: there is no need to go to step4 if each site has independent cookie check my answer to set cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood that I cannot use set cookie from one site into another. and the domain parameter in setcookie is used only for subdomains . . .

so all this code is not relevant.